# Create Http Request for testing purpose

Tags: c#, http, testing

I need something quite different from question with similar subject.

I'm wondering if exist a .NET library that creates a **real http request stream** (obviously in parametric way).
This is not for ASP.NET or other web framework, I want a raw stream of bytes (not mock objects of various *http contexts*).

I have intentionally omitted *fake* from the question title, because I need a real http request but I do not want a component that sent it over the network.

[note by ebohlman]: If I read you correctly, a clearer way of putting it is "... creates a simulated http request stream (at the raw-byte level) based on supplied parameters ..."

Basically I should be able to (it follows pseudo-C#):

```
[Fact]
void Parse_http_request_headers() {
  HttpRequest req = HttpRequestBuilder.Create(HttpMethod.Get, "http://someserver/app/etc/etc");

  HttpParser parser = new HttpParser(req.ToByteArray());

  parser.Method.Should().Be("GET");
  parser.Scheme.Should().Be("http");
  // Remainder omitted
}
```

I just want to know if someone already created something like this.

Comment: I need to write a strong http protocol implementation, hence primarly an (error free) http parser.

Comment: @ebohlman, agree with your editing. In fact I'm try to get exactly this result. If anyone suggests something already done, I'll publish a first draft on github, when done. (And a link here for reference).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a program that uses [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) to capture and save the request stream. Run it on your local computer.

Then, in a separate program, create a regular `HttpWebRequest` and send it to the program that's listening. The listener saves the stream to a binary file, and you now have a request stream that you can examine.

Comment: Mimschel, I've evaluated this option before posting the question. From some initial investigation, it seems uncomfortable in automated test scenario. In fact this is why I say 'I do not want ... sent over the network'. Maybe I was not precise, but 'localhost <-> localhost' was included. Anyway, thank for replying with precise description (+1).

Comment: As promised I can finally share my work that do exactly what I needed: https://github.com/gsscoder/surfhttp. Just please take into account that this is an alfa of a work in progress.